# Views in ViewGroups in a ViewGroup

Tags: android

I've implemented my own custom `ViewGroup`, containing zero or more other `ViewGroup`. All `ViewGroup`s and `View`s are inflated from XML resources. Leaving out some trivial parts, the code looks roughly like this:

```
public class OuterLayout extends ViewGroup {
    public OuterLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int c = getChildCount(); View v;

        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            v = getChildAt(i);

            // in reality different values are calculated for each child
            v.layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }
}

public class InnerLayout extends ViewGroup {
    public InnerLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        View v = findViewById(R.id.childView);

        // in reality different values are calculated for each child
        v.layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
}

public class ChildView extends View {
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // do some drawing
    }
}
```

The ultimate problem here is that the `ChildView`s aren't being drawn at all, but the `InnerLayout`s are. The `onDraw` method in `ChildView` isn't called at all, but the `onLayout`methods in both of the `ViewGroup`s are. I've more or less solved this problem by implementing the `onDraw` method in the `InnerLayout` and calling the `draw` method of all `ChildView`s, but I feel like this is not the best solution for this problem and might eventually lead to other problems, especially because the `Canvas` of the `InnerLayout` is passed to the `ChildView`.

In an earlier stage of development the `ChildView`s where locatied inside the `OuterLayout`, which worked fine. My question is, why doesn't it work when the `InnerLayout` is placed in between?

Edit: the XML from which the `ViewGroup`s and `View`s are inflated. The `InnerLayout` is added to the `OuterLayout` programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.OuterLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.InnerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.ChildView
        android:id="@+id/childView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.example.OuterLayout>
```

Comment: Are all these classes in one file?

Comment: What is `getChildAtIndex()`? I see only `getChildAt()` as a method of `ViewGroup`. Are you sure that `onDraw()` for the child is not being called and you just don't have a problem with drawing the child? Your XML might be helpful.

Comment: did you override `dispatchDraw` methods? `"Called by draw to draw the child views. This may be overridden by derived classes to gain control just before its children are drawn (but after its own view has been drawn)."`

Comment: @azizbekian No, each class is in its own file.

Comment: @Cheticamp That's a type in the post so I'll change it. It's correct in the actual code though. The XML is pretty straightforward, but I'll add it.

Comment: @pskink I did not, so that won't be the problem I think.

Comment: I do think the @pskink is on to something. I put together a dummy project with your code and the child view is created and displayed with an invocation of `super.onDraw()`.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/CustomViewGroups) is the MCVE I put together on GitHub. Maybe you can use it to help track down your issue. The circle within the red box comes from `ChildView`.

Comment: @Cheticamp I've duplicated your code in my project but I'm only seeing the `OuterLayout` and the `InnerLayout` - the `ChildView` is not drawn at all. What Android API version does your emulator run?

Comment: API 24 I think.

Comment: Also works on AVD with API 17.